# Generate CSV file with JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

Am using `JasperReports` to generate report in `CSV` format. What I want to do is make column to has a selection list with values ('yes', 'No'). Is that doable with `JasperReports`?

Answer (score 0):

This is not duable with CSV.
CSV is "comma-separated-values". Even though in most systems it would open in Excel, it is actually just values with commas in between, and therefore does not support the full capabilities of Excel.